# HashSet limit - how to proceed?

Tags: c#, .net, set, hashset, gethashcode

My program creates custom objects, I want to get a distinct list of. So I want to use a set and add object by object. The set would prevent duplicates. And at last I have a set of unique objects.

I would usually use a HashSet, because I don't need a sorted set. Only, there are so many different potential objects. More than 2^32. The GetHashCode function returns an int, so this cannot work as a unique key for my objects.

I assume that I cannot use the HashSet hence and must use the slower SortedSet and have my object implement IComparable / CompareTo. Is this correct? Or is there a way to have a HashSet with long hash codes?

Comment: A HashSet cannot contain more than 2^31 items. This will limit you as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`GetHashCode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does return an int, but if the comparison for the hash codes determines they are the same, it folllows by calling the [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (which you should override).

So, no, you don't have to switch. You can keep using the same old lovable [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (as long as you don't run out of memory).

Comment: A hash code does not need to be unique, that is what hashing is all about. Creating hash codes are creating small identifiers for large objects, that obviously is never going to create an unique code for all possible object states.

Comment: @I3arnon: Thank you very much for the simple and clear explanation.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner sure, any time.

Comment: @PMF: You are right. Only, I didn't know that the HashSet uses the Equals method at all, so it seemed to me it used the hash code as a unique identifyer (one object per bucket). Now I know better. Thanks for your comment.